# In WPF style how to correct bind parent checkbox property to a child?

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

I'm new to WPF styling and I cannot make next thing to work:
I've got a custom checkbox style with another checkbox in it. I need parent "IsChecked" value to change as "contolCheckBox" child in ControlTemplate changes.
Tryed different triggers but can't get to parent property.
For now I've got next xaml code:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="27" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFBABAC7" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="contolCheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <ContentPresenter  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=contolCheckBox}"/>
    <!---->
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF29E200"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Firebrick"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

"IsChecked" value of control doesn`t changes.
What am I doing wrong?

```
Binding ElementName=contolCheckBox, Path=IsChecked
```

not working too.

Comment: Try `Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=controlCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}"`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn`t help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `controlCheckBox` is within the name scope since it's declared within the `ControlTemplate`. So your binding isn't working. Instead, invert your binding and bind from the bottom up. What you're looking for in a sitation like this is template binding. Try this in your`ControlTemplate` ..

```
<CheckBox x:Name="contolCheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"
          IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Note the `RelativeSouce`binding. This indicates that I want to bind to the parent of the template. This is the common way to bind underlying `ControlTemplate` controls to parent properties.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It`s worked. Didn`t tried this way as I thought this way will bind FROM parent TO child and forgot about TwoWay mode to work ot otherwise.